# How to pass a query as a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

```
DECLARE @SomeVariableTable TABLE (
    Field INT
)
INSERT INTO @SomeVariableTable
    SELECT    st.Field
    FROM      SomeTable st;

SELECT    *

FROM      AnotherTable at

WHERE     at.SomeField IN @SomeVariableTable
```

How can I make the above code work?

I have looked at concatenating the entire column into a VARCHAR and while this works for VARCHARs it doesn't work for INTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost fine except the last `SELECT`. Change the last `SELECT` part as below.

```
SELECT    *
FROM      AnotherTable at    
WHERE     at.SomeField IN (select Field from @SomeVariableTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do what you are trying to do .....

```
DECLARE @SomeVariableTable TABLE (
    Field INT
)
INSERT INTO @SomeVariableTable
    SELECT    st.Field
    FROM      SomeTable st;

SELECT    *
FROM      AnotherTable at
WHERE     at.SomeField IN (
                           SELECT Field
                           FROM @SomeVariableTable
                           )
```

But why would you do this anyway? you could have simply done something like

```
SELECT    *
FROM      AnotherTable at
WHERE     at.SomeField IN (
                           SELECT Field
                           FROM SomeTable
                           )
```

Comment: Because for testing purposes I need to recreate the parameters that would usually be supplied through a parameter select box.